# Inactive user function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to write code for if someone has loaded my website but is then inactive on my site as they are looking at another website. To then run a Jquery function to do something weird with my website while they are gone.

I have looked at methods such as this (But I don't want to code this, to find I could have done something faster or wasting my time on something else.)... http://www.paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/

However all I want to know is when someone isn't actually on my page... would you recommend I use the above code or should I use a if mouse over body then run function? type function?

So really I'm just asking what you all advise I should do. I haven't written any code as I'm not sure on which code I should go about writing, I wouldn't normally ask here first however I have spent many weeks focusing on the wrong code and found my problems answered within an hour of posting here for a previous problem. So I wanted to just check on advise first.

Many thanks to anyone with an idea of how I should go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the `window.onblur` event fired. It doesn't guarantee the user loaded another tab, it only means that the window lost focus. For example:

```
window.onblur = function() {
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3WbNd/ (click the result panel, then click outside it)

Comment: omg really thank you saved me sooo much time :) thanks a load